# Disabling the button based on items selected in the ItemsList

Tags: xaml

```
<Button ToolTip="Duplicate" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
            Command="{Binding Path=DuplicateEntityCommand }"
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=GridView, Path=SelectedItems}">
                <Image Style="{StaticResource toolbarImageStyle}" Source="/OnePlanner;component/Resources/Icons/duplicate.png"></Image>
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">                           
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=RadGridView, Path=SelectedItems.Count}" Value="1"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsItemListConstainsToyota}" Value="False"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>                          
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
```

The button is tied with the GridView. I have to enable this button based on the selection in SelectedItems. If one selects only one items in the grid and that item does not has let say a string with value equal to Toyota, then the button should be enabled. 
I have created a method in viewmodel that I use with commandParameter.

```
private bool IsItemListConstainsToyota(IList<object> itemList)
    {
        if (itemList.First() is CarList)
        {
            String carName= ((CarList)itemList.First()).carNameAsString;
            if (carName.Equals("Toyota"))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The code so far I have does not work. Is there anyway to do in XAML or I have to do it in viewModel?

Comment: Does your "IsItemListConstainsToyota"-method trigger? Have you put a breakpoint in it to follow the flow through it?

Comment: Yes, it get triggered.

Comment: Then, does it return the correct value?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your questions. The method does not get triggered from <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsItemListConstainsToyota}" Value="False"/>. I have to find an alternate way to call this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Duplicate Entity Command, you can pass `Action<object>` for CanExecuteAction. If this is false, then your button will be disabled. Try passing the following `Action<object>` to the CanExecuteParameter in ICommand.

```
    itemList =>
    {
         return IsItemListConstainsToyota(itemList);
    }
```